# sqlite3 with docker throws MODULE_NOT_FOUND error

Tags: node.js, docker, docker-compose, node-sqlite3

My node application works on my local(MacOS), but it does not work if I use docker.

1. it works if I try local:
   npm install
   npm start
2. It throws error if I try docker
   docker-compose build
   docker-compose up

I'm getting this error.
`Error: Cannot find module '/src/node_modules/sqlite3/lib/binding/napi-v6-linux-musl-x64/node_sqlite3.node'`

Package.json

```
{
  "name": "api",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "API",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "rm -rf usersdb.sqlite && jest --forceExit",
    "test:coverage": "npm run test -- --coverage --forceExit",
    "start": "nodemon app.js"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "bcryptjs": "^2.4.3",
    "body-parser": "^1.20.1",
    "cors": "^2.8.5",
    "dotenv": "^10.0.0",
    "express": "^4.18.2",
    "jsonwebtoken": "^9.0.0",
    "lodash": "^4.17.21",
    "mysql": "^2.18.1",
    "nodemon": "^2.0.20",
    "sqlite3": "^5.1.4"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "jest": "^28.1.1",
    "supertest": "^6.3.3"
  }
}
```

docker-compose.yml

```
version: "3.7"
services:
  api:
    image: test/api
    build: ./
    command: npm start
    restart: on-failure
    environment:
      SERVER_PORT: 3004
      TOKEN_KEY: test123
    volumes:
      - .:/src
    ports:
      - "3004:3004"
```

Dockerfile

```
FROM node:12.22-alpine as base

WORKDIR /src
COPY package*.json ./
EXPOSE 3004

RUN apk add --no-cache python2 g++ make

RUN npm install
FROM base as dev
ENV NODE_ENV=development
RUN npm install -g nodemon
COPY . ./
CMD ["nodemon", "app.js"]
```

Answer (score 0):

Delete the `volumes:` block from your `docker-compose.yml`.

The `volumes:` block in your `docker-compose.yml` file is overwriting your entire application with content from your host system.  That includes overwriting the Linux-OS `node_modules` tree with the MacOS version from your host system.

You don't need this `volumes:` block.  The code and `node_modules:` tree are built into your image.  If you need to develop your application, you can install Node on your host system (on MacOS this might be as little as `brew install node`) and use that for day-to-day development, even if you're planning to eventually use Docker for final deployment or if you have dependencies that run in containers.